# how to encode the value of "point" which we get from google maps api

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkmapview, encode

I want the  decoded value of "point" which we get when we call following  google api http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false

Here the value of "points" is encoded i want the decoded value of it as i want the lat ,lon value to be used in my project in iphone.

Thanks and Regards
Mrugen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of this ending format is described on Google's map API [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html).

You may code this decoding utility yourself or you can grab the code from [here](http://fkn1337.com/decode-google-maps-polylines-objective-c/) or [here](http://sapessi.com/2010/06/decode-a-gpolyline-in-objective-c/).